# Having issue with Bindable value in XAML page

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have code that is a sample bowling recap where 3 games are entered and are summarized in a Series column. The problem that I am experiencing is the Series column is not getting updated as I anticipate. Obviously, I am doing something wrong but can not see what I am doing wrong. Below is the code that supports the application:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HoriView.MainPage">
    
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Spacing="25"
                Padding="30,0"
                VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Image
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
                <Label
                    Text="Hello, Bowlers!"
                    FontSize="32"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
                <Label
                    Text="Bowling Recap Snippet"
                    FontSize="18"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
            </VerticalStackLayout>
    
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView>
            <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <CollectionView SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding scores}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Game}" FontSize="Medium" WidthRequest="83" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"></Label>
                               <Entry Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Score}" TextChanged="UpdateGame" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next" Placeholder="Game" WidthRequest="83" FontSize="Medium" ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    
namespace HoriView;
    
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Games> scores { get; set; }
    string header = "Game";
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        scores= new ObservableCollection<Games>();
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3)
            {
                header = "Series";
            }
            else
            {
                header = "Game" + (i+1).ToString();
            }
            scores.Add(new Games() 
            { 
                Game=header, 
                Score=0
            });
                
        }
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    
    public void UpdateGame(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        scores[scores.Count-1].Score = 0;
        for(int i=0; i< scores.Count-1; i++) 
        {
            scores[scores.Count - 1].Score += scores[i].Score;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Games
{
    public string Game { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Series column is not getting updated" - there is nothing in your UI labelled "Series".  Which specific UI element are you talking about?  And "not getting updated" - do you mean the value is correct when the page loads, but is not updated when you update the data?  Or if not that, then what specifically is the problem?  More than likely the problem is that `Games` is not [Observable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject)

Comment: Games is Observable [public ObservableCollection<Games> scores { get; set; }]. I noticed in the debugging that the scores [Games] array is getting updated as scores are added for each Game. The view of the data in the XAML does not get updated in the Series column. Hope this helps to understand my dilemma.

Comment: Change this {Binding scores} to this {Binding Scores}. Capital S is important. Also change all scores to Scores. ObservableCollection creates code behind at the build process for you.

Comment: The **Games** class is NOT Observable

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas The uppercase "S" won't make a difference here, because there's no backing field of the same name with a lowercase "s", although it is a common convention to name properties with capital letters.

Comment: @Shades49 your Games class is not raising any `PropertyChanged` events. You need to make the properties `Game` and `Score` observable by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. There are several different ways to do this. One way is to inherit from `ObservableObject` (MVVM Community Toolkit) and using Source Generators, another is to implement it manually.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas, understood with respect to case sensitivity. And you are right, the uppercase "S" is not relevant in this case.

Comment: @ewerspej, I attempted INotifyPropertyChanged interface but to no avail. I may have coded incorrectly and will address again.

Comment: You need a ViewModel to do that. Use 
public partial class GameViewModel: ObservableObject and move all the logic there. If you need more code let me know.

Comment: Technically, a ViewModel isn't strictly needed. The issue here should be the missing `PropertyChanged` notifications. However, using ViewModels and MVVM is a common design decision and the recommended way to implement MAUI apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Games` class doesn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

You can either implement that manually:

```cs
public class Games : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _game;
    public string Game
    {
        get => _game;
        set
        {
            if(_game == value) return;
            _game = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _score;
    public int Score
    {
        get => _score;
        set
        {
            if(_score == value) return;
            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  
}
```

Alternatively, you could also inherit from `ObservableObject` from the [MVVM Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) and then simply write the following using Source Generators:

```cs
public partial class Games : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _game;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _score;
}
```

In this case, you only define the backing fields and the Source Generators will create the uppercase, observable properties `Game` and `Score` for you.

Comment: To all those who have responded to this posting, especially to ewerspej, thank you for your input.